# Iterate through similar model field names in template (e.g. FieldName1, FieldName2, etc.)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Fairly new to Django and Python, but trying my best to learn how to clean my code. Currently, I have a model called Recipe that can hold 30 steps (Field Names = Step1, Step2, etc.) and 30 ingredients (Field Names = Ingredient1, Ingredient2, etc.) amongst other fields. The snippet of code below works great, but I am currently manually doing this for all 30 table rows up to Step30, Ingredient30, etc.

I've tried setting up a for loop that places {{ i }} at the end of the Field Name to generate up to 30, but am generating parsing issues. I've also tried placing the Field Names in a list or dictionary and looping through them that way, but ultimately will only generate the name of the string, not the attributes value.

Below is my setup, which as I mentioned currently works.

HTML

```
<tr>
  <td>
    {% if recipe.hot_ingredient_icon1 %}
      <img src="{% static 'img/icons/hot-icon.png' %}" alt="hot-icon" class="ingredient-key-icon">
    {% endif %}
    {% if recipe.cansub_ingredient_icon1 %}
      <img src="{% static 'img/icons/substitute-icon.png' %}" alt="subsitute-icon" class="ingredient-key- 
      icon">
    {% endif %}
    {% if recipe.fresh_or_ground_ingredient_icon1 %}
      <img src="{% static 'img/icons/fresh-or-ground-icon.png' %}" alt="fresh-or-ground-icon" 
      class="ingredient-key-icon">
    {% endif %}
  </td>
  {% if recipe.ingredient1 %}
  <td>{{ recipe.ingredient1 }}</td>
  {% endif %}
  {% if recipe.step1 %}
  <td>1. &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ recipe.step1 }}</td>
  {% endif %}
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    {% if recipe.hot_ingredient_icon2 %}
      <img src="{% static 'img/icons/hot-icon.png' %}" alt="hot-icon" class="ingredient-key-icon">
    {% endif %}
    {% if recipe.cansub_ingredient_icon2 %}
      <img src="{% static 'img/icons/substitute-icon.png' %}" alt="subsitute-icon" class="ingredient-key- 
      icon">
    {% endif %}
    {% if recipe.fresh_or_ground_ingredient_icon2 %}
      <img src="{% static 'img/icons/fresh-or-ground-icon.png' %}" alt="fresh-or-ground-icon" 
      class="ingredient-key-icon">
    {% endif %}
  </td>
  {% if recipe.ingredient2 %}
  <td>{{ recipe.ingredient2 }}</td>
  {% endif %}
  {% if recipe.step2 %}
  <td>2. &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ recipe.step2 }}</td>
  {% endif %}
</tr>
```

Views.py (included to understand the general set up of my class based view, but the def get_template_names and def get_queryset are not really being relied upon in this question).

```
class RecipeSearchList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Recipe

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['recipes/search.html']

    def get_queryset(self):
        recipe_name_query = self.request.GET.get('recipe_name')

    recipe_item = models.Recipe.objects.all()

    if recipe_name_query:
        recipe_item = recipe_item.filter(recipe_name__icontains=recipe_name_query)

    return recipe_item
```

Urls.py (relevant code)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("search/", views.RecipeSearchList.as_view(), name="search"),
]
```

My understanding is that I need to do something in my views.py file to make this work, but am open to the most effective option. Thanks for the help!

Models.py (included for context)

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

from countries.models import Country

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Recipe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="recipes", on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    # If we delete a chef the recipe still will exist
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name="recipes", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    cook_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default = 30,
        validators= [
            MaxValueValidator(4320),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ]
    )
    serving_size = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default = 4,
        validators = [
            MaxValueValidator(12),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ]
    )
    diet_gluten_free = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    diet_ketogenic = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    diet_vegan = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    diet_vegetarian = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    allergin_dairy = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    allergin_egg = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    allergin_nuts = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    allergin_shellfish = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    allergin_soy = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    allergin_wheat = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    recipe_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_show_recipe = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    step1 = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    step2 = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    step3 = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank=True)
    ...
    step30 = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank=True)
    ingredient1 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    ingredient2 = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    ingredient3 = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    ...
    ingredient30 = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    hot_ingredient_icon1 = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    ...
    hot_ingredient_icon30 = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    cansub_ingredient_icon1 = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    ...
    cansub_ingredient_icon30 = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    fresh_or_ground_ingredient_icon1 = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    ...
    fresh_or_ground_ingredient_icon30 = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "recipes:single",
            kwargs={
                "username": self.user.username,
                "pk": self.pk
            }
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_date"]
        unique_together = ["user", "recipe_name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should user Foreign Relations

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="recipes", on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    # If we delete a chef the recipe still will exist
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name="recipes", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    
class Step(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

that way you can use this inside your template

```
{% for step in recipe.step_set %}
    {{ step }}
{% endfor %}
```

the step_set variable will have the related steps of the recipe

Comment: Are you able to expand on this a little further? I am trying to figure out how the 30 individual steps, ingredients, etc. will be uploaded and stored in my models and then placed in the step_set variable. For example, the Step model you noted about has a relationship with the Recipe model (which is great), but there is only 1 description field. Shouldn't there be 30 of these fields to loop through, which I would pass them all into the step_set variable?

Comment: try to think like this, forget the steps and ingredients and make the view to create the recipe. When you have your recipe created, then you can create a link to another view where you create the steps por the recipe

Comment: I am still trying to replicate your example above... The issue I am running into now is how to loop through the Ingredient and Step models to get them to display in the table correctly (I can pull in the data, but can't place it in an organized table). Also, I ended up using related names along of the lines of {% for ingredient in recipe.ingredients.all %} as the _set would not work.